# ESP8266 Not running Arduino code when uploaded

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I have just recently got some ESP8266's and Ive been trying to use the Arduino IDE 1.8 to program them. (I have also used versions 1.6.5 and 1.6.9).

I have successfully ported a custom build from [here](https://nodemcu-build.com) and it runs perfectly, I upload Lua code and it runs with no problem.

But when I try to run the Arduino code (Such as the blink example found [on this tutorial](http://iot-playground.com/blog/2-uncategorised/38-esp8266-and-arduino-ide-blink-example), with an LED on GPIO 2) that successfully uploads every time, the code never runs. In the Serial program on my PC, I won't see any text, (and the LED will be constantly on).

I followed several online tutorials saying pretty much the same procedure and no luck. Has anyone else experienced this issue and know the solution? Thanks!

Comment: Did you remember to disconnect GPIO-0 from ground after uploading and then connect RESET to ground briefly?

Comment: @Richard210363 Yes I did both of those. I've also disconnected and reconnected power.

Comment: It sounds like either a supply issue or that you did not connect CH_PD pin to 3.3v.

Comment: @XerXeX I'll have to retry and double check everything again. The 3.3v supply should be enough (Using an old PC power supply) and I did connect the CH_PD pin.